# Burninate [spring-rabbit]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

The [`spring-rabbit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbit) tag has 449 questions tagged on the site.  However, the feature described by the tag is officially named "[spring-amqp](https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp)".

This tag is duplicative of two other tags, with the primary tag being the `spring-amqp` tag (1233 questions).

Burninate criteria:

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

The answer to both is "no."  First, the product name is not aligned with the tag (as noted). Second, there is a [`spring-rabbitmq`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbitmq) tag (see [burninate request for spring-rabbitmq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391175/burninate-spring-rabbitmq)) as well as a [`spring-amqp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-amqp) tag. Technically, one question could be tagged with all three tags, each of which refer to the same exact thing.

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes.

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No, and I would further add it is harmful. Spreading the same product across three tags reduces the likelihood that the right individuals will see the question.

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

I believe the tag, by itself, would mean the same no matter the context. The issue is that it is duplicative.

Comment: I would recommend to simply retag the questions properly, if there is guidance already instead of going through the burnination process.

Comment: @Dharman - certainly it is possible; however, what is to prevent future users from tagging the questions again?

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 tags currently. One is about [Spring-amqp](https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp) and the other one is about a specific implementation called Spring-rabbit. You would like to burninate 2 of them, which are both on-topic and unambiguous. The only problem with them is that they are messy. The community should agree to keep only 2 of them, and make the third one an alias. No need to burninate anything.

I would suggest to keep [spring-amqp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-amqp) separate, and make [spring-rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbitmq) as a synonym of [spring-rabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbit). Don't burninate anything.

Comment: How does a tag synonym get set?

Comment: I also don't agree with keeping three. As there is only one implementation, having multiple tags does not make sense at the current time. Perhaps we could keep spring-rabbit and make spring-amqp a synonym?

Comment: You suggest a synonym on a synonym page and after it gets approved by others it will be synonymized. However, it is best to let the experts discuss this here on Meta first.

Comment: @theMayer You post a [tag:retag-request] on meta and if it gets a favorable response one of the mods uses a tool and creates it with a few clicks.  This has the considerable advantage of being almost instant; the burnination backlog was about a half dozen years long prior to it grinding to a halt due to the mod running it going on strike.

Comment: @DanNeely - thank you for the helpful information, that sounds reasonable.

Comment: The synonym relationship has been created as of today: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404136/retag-spring-rabbitmq-to-spring-rabbit#404136