# Should [spring-rabbit] and [spring-amqp] be merged?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

The [spring-rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbitmq) tag was made a synonym of the [spring-rabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbit) tag.  There is also a [spring-amqp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-amqp) tag.

Per the [Spring AMQP](https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp) documentation, these are two separate things: the base abstraction and the RabbitMQ implementation of the abstraction:

> The project consists of two parts; spring-amqp is the base abstraction, and spring-rabbit is the RabbitMQ implementation.

I haven't been able to find any evidence of the existence of non-RabbitMQ implementations of Spring AMQP, either in the Spring AMQP documentation or in a web search.

Of the 1373 questions tagged [spring-amqp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-amqp), only [150 of them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bspring-amqp%5D+-%5Bspring-rabbit%5D+-%5Brabbitmq%5D+-rabbit+-rabbitmq+-rabbittemplate+-rabbitlistener+is%3Aquestion) weren't tagged with either [spring-rabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbit), [rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rabbitmq), or didn't contain "Rabbit", "RabbitMQ", "RabbitTemplate", or "RabbitListener" (I couldn't find a way to exclude anything containing "rabbit" from my search).

Given these points, is there value to having separate `spring-amqp` and `spring-rabbit` tags?  If not, a tag synonym seems appropriate.

I saw one bit of [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391176/1108305) on this as part of an answer to a related burnination question on Meta that suggested against it:

> There are 3 tags currently. One is about [Spring-amqp](https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp) and the other one is about a specific implementation called Spring-rabbit. You would like to burninate 2 of them, which are both on-topic and unambiguous. The only problem with them is that they are messy. The community should agree to keep only 2 of them, and make the third one an alias. No need to burninate anything.
>
> I would suggest to keep [spring-amqp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-amqp) separate, and make [spring-rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbitmq) as a synonym of [spring-rabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-rabbit). Don't burninate anything.

Comment: I don't see why the fact that spring-rabbit is the only ((widely?) known, or public) implementation of spring-amqp would be a reason to make spring-amqp an alias for spring-rabbit. For example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39716281/466862) shows someone who created a quick and dirty implementation for spring-amqp for Apache Qpid. The question just isn't tagged with spring-amqp.

Comment: Could you link the source of that quote? The current link on _"discussion"_ points to the search you also link from _"150 of them"_. Also, please explain why you bring it up again, when the previous discussion on this subject - judging by that quote - concluded that spring-amqp and spring-rabbit should be kept separate?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Fixed the link; looks like I made a copy/paste error.  I brought it up again since it was part of a different (albeit related) discussion (whether to burninate [tag:spring-rabbit]).  It felt like it deserved its own discussion by the community now that the biggest offender ([tag:spring-rabbit] vs. [tag:spring-rabbitmq]) has been addressed, and it didnt' feel that a post on a separate issue was the appropriate way to decided this issue.